# PineScript for certain stock tickers?

Tags: pine-script

Hello everyone PineScript noob here. Just had a quick question about the capabilities of PineScript. Can PineScript add certain indicators for specific stock tickers? Id like to add certain S/R levels that are different for each ticker, and have a library that I keep updated. Would this be possible? Thanks! :)

Comment: Pinescript will update values on chart as you change it but it will not export your indicator data

Answer (score 0):

I believe it can using the syminfo.root variable, just say i wanted a different sma value on my stochastic for GBPAUD;

```
if (syminfo.root == "GBPAUD")
    K:=sma(stoch(close, high, low, 8), 3)
    D:=sma(K, 3)
```